# Combine Rows based Off Condition and Combine Other Rows Based Off Another Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table in SQL server that looks like this:

```
Name      Value
a           1
b          23
c          15 
d          57 
e          98
```

I need to transform it to this:

```
New Name      Value
a-c           39        (a+b+c)
d-e           155       (d+e)
```

Comment: So it looks like you are aggregating some name ranges... but what is the condition you use for aggregation?

Comment: The names have an order. In the example It would be alphabetical, but it wouldn't always be by three. Might be a-b and then c-h.

Comment: So how would you decide whether it was to be a-b and c-h, rather than a-c and d-e?

Comment: Requirements that I have for a SSRS report. They want them in different groups but the groups are different sizes. No idea why, but that's the way it's laid out.

Comment: Then you need to ask how to define those groups.

Comment: @auwall12688 - there must be a logic behind the grouping (even if you tell us that it should be random), or just **isn't possible** to do this

Comment: @auwall12688: Do they want to be able to define the groupings at report run time?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to group by 3s, try:

```
select min([Name]) + '-' + max([Name]) [New Name], sum([Value]) [Value]
from
(select [Name], [Value], row_number() over (order by [Name]) rn
from myTable) sq
group by floor((rn-1)/3)
```